# Customize WooCommerce order email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

I'm using WooCommerce for my website. I need to change the body of the email in 'Cancelled order'. I want to add my own content in the email body, There is no option to edit the body in the dashboard. Are there any hooks to change the email body?
[image]

Comment: See if this help you : https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/customize-woocommerce-order-emails/

Comment: Yes read this too. We can only edit the template file here, I'm finding a way to give this option through the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override Cancelled order email template.

To override and edit this email template copy :
 **woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-cancelled-order.php** to your theme folder: **yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-cancelled-order.php**.
Now edit this file to change simple table header changes.

If you need to change table body content then you need to copy: 
**woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php** to your theme folder: **yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php**, 
because from **admin-cancelled-order.php** file table body, this function
`<?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( false, true ); ?>`
 
is called which in turns calls the template **email-order-items.php**.

Comment: Thanks. I have read this from Woothemes, But here we need to edit the template file, I'm finding a way that, admin can add some extra text to the mail body through the wordpress dashboard. Because admin don't have a coding knowledge.