# Add custom info in woocommerce email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, hook-woocommerce

Before I updated all my plugins and WP I had some information displaying in the new order woo email after the total. Like: customer note, email and phone.

But after the updates they are gone. I do not know from where is this information come from. I tried to look in the woo settings but I did not find anything.

Does someone know how to put them back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize WooCommerce order email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996319/customize-woocommerce-order-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, including this code in the function.php

```
function wc_customer_details( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    if ( empty( $fields ) ) {
        if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
            $fields['customer_note'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'Customer Note', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ),
            );
        }
        if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) {
            $fields['billing_email'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_email() ),
            );
        }
        if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) {
            $fields['billing_phone'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_phone() ),
            );
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'wc_customer_details', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For an example,

```
 // Edit order items table template defaults
function sww_add_wc_order_email_images( $table, $order ) {

ob_start();

$template = $plain_text ? 'emails/plain/email-order-items.php' : 'emails/email-order-items.php';
wc_get_template( $template, array(
    'order'                 => $order,
    'items'                 => $order->get_items(),
    'show_download_links'   => $show_download_links,
    'show_sku'              => $show_sku,
    'show_purchase_note'    => $show_purchase_note,
    'show_image'            => true,
    'image_size'            => $image_size
) );

return ob_get_clean();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_table', 'sww_add_wc_order_email_images', 10, 2 );
```

For more details,

[Link 1](https://www.sellwithwp.com/how-to-add-information-to-woocommerce-emails/), 
[Link 2](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-extra-content-order-email/),
[Link 3](https://www.sellwithwp.com/customizing-woocommerce-order-emails/),
[Link 4](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-custom-field-in-an-order-to-the-emails/)

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: what it is on link 3. The template picture there is a customer details area with email and phone. It is exactly how it was in my new orders email, this area is not there anymore.