# woocommerce custom email templates php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, templates, woocommerce

I am stuck in resolving custom email templates to `woocomerce`. I read dozens of forums ([Customize WooCommerce order email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996319/customize-woocommerce-order-email)), and I do have my the custom email template in the right folder, but woocommerce does send the original one. I also tried to modify the plain email templates in the woocommerce folder, but it still didn't work. I don't understand from where can it take such a text, when I have deleted it from all occurences.

The path to my custom email template: `mytheme/resource/woocommerce/emails`, I tried also `mytheme/woocommerce/emails`

The path to the original templates: `woocommerce/templates/emails` and `woocommerce/templates/emails/plain`

I tried modifying all of them. In wp admin, I see the right, modified email templates, but still the system sends the original one.

Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: are you working on custom theme or purchased theme?

Comment: custom theme, do you think the custom theme messes up?

Comment: Yes, It may cause an issue. please apply below my answer. Hope it will surely resolve your issue.

Comment: It has resolved the issue for the most of my email, also there is one (customer-processing-order.php) which still cannot be overrriden. For this one I modified the woocomerce template in the woocomerce plugin's folder. I restored the plugin files, but this one still not works

Answer (score 1):

You need add folder woocommerce in your theme. Then you can override any template.

For example:

```
yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php
```

It's work fine. I checked it.

P.S [Overriding templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: unfortunately I already tried it, and it does not work for me

Comment: A link to a picture about my folder structure : (dont know yet how to insert picture) [link](https://kepkuldes.com/image/eNYn5t)

Comment: Maybe problem in some function hook in your theme, could you please check it?

Comment: Yes, I needed to add the function above

Answer (score 1):

As you are using custom theme, It is mandatory to declare support for the external functionality.
WooCommerce is one of the external functionality.So please add a theme support for the same.

WooCommerce template overrides are only enabled on themes that declare WooCommerce support. If you do not declare WooCommerce support in your theme, WooCommerce will assume the theme is not designed for WooCommerce compatibility and will use shortcode-based unsupported theme rendering to display the shop.

Add below snippet in your theme's functions.php

```
 function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
 }
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

and then you can override the WooCommerce Template as per your need.

[REFERENCE LINK](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes)